# Unexpected behavior when checking file size

Tags: bash, process, proc

I'm trying to write a 1 line bash script that will get all PIDs of processes that look like kernel processes, and check to see if they have contents in `/proc/*/maps`, which indicated kernel process masquerading.

I currently have the following script:

```
for pid in $(ps aux | grep "\["  | awk -F' ' '{print $2}');do if [ -s /proc/$pid/maps ]; then echo $pid; fi;  done
```

The script should output the pid if `/proc/$pid/maps` size is greater than 0. However, the script outputs nothing.

`if [ -s /proc/$pid/maps ]` is supposed to indicate if the file is not empty. It doesn't seem to be working.

I could work around this using another method but this `-s` option is what the internet recommends to check if a file is empty or not.

Whats the issue here? I do know there is one process with a bracket in its command line (avahi daemon) which will have contents in `/proc/$pid/maps`, so there should be at least 1 pid output for testing purposes. If I remove the grep from the pipe, so it iterates over all pids, there is still no output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that files under `/proc/$pid` have an apparent size of 0, regardless of their contents; compare the outputs of

```
ls -l /proc/*/maps
```

and

```
wc -c /proc/*/maps
```

To check the size of `/proc/$pid/maps` you need to actually read it, using *e.g.* `wc -c` as above.